# NotificationHub RegisterNativeAsync with CancellationToken

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, azure-notificationhub, cancellation-token

I have a WP app that use NotificationHub.

To register the user, I call RegisterNativeAsync.

However, some users having slow connection raise to me that the loading is very long.

Is it possible to pass a CancellationToken when calling RegisterNativeAsync ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `RegisterNativeAsync` doesn't directly support a cancellation token itself but if you want to add a timeout you could do this by having another task which creates a timeout and using `Task.WhenAny` to simulate this.

As this is an awaitable method there should be no need for this to be causing any kind of delay for the user.
Perhaps you need to look at the UX around this call.

Comment: Hmm, ok. But I think using Task.WhenAny will just set the timeout, but actually it is still sending the async request, isn't it ? 

Actually I want to make sure that the user really is registered. 
If it is too long, I just want to cancel the current one, and inform the user. I guess I need to find a workaround on my logic now.

Thanks